# extract multiple params from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

I have a rails app and I'd like to extract 2 different ids from this url:

`http://localhost:3000/shopping/suppliers/2/products/1`

Looking at the `development.log` it seems like both values are there.

I'm wondering how I can expose these params to the controller, is it just `params[:supplier_id]` and `params[:id]`?

```
Started GET "/shopping/suppliers/2/products/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-22 18:28:19 +1000
Processing by Shopping::ProductsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"supplier_id"=>"2", "id"=>"1"}
  Product Load (30.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."permalink" = $1  ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["permalink", "1"]]
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (19.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."permalink" = $1  ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["permalink", "1"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered shopping/products/show.html.haml within layouts/mdl (0.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_meta_data.html.haml (0.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_top_cart.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_compact_menu.html.haml (4.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 46.2ms | ActiveRecord: 50.8ms)
```

Comment: yes! you can access those values as params[:supplier_id] and params[:id].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to access your values with those keys:

```
params[:supplier_id]
params[:id]
```

It is wierd why you have not tried your own suggestion before posting your question. :)

Comment: is this the best method to be doing this, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: This sure is the cleanest way possible. Does it look dirty to you?